# $X,Y$ i.i.d., $X$ and $(X+Y)/\sqrt{2}$ have the same dist., then show that $X$ has a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I am trying to show that $X$ is a standard normal (in distribution) by applying the Lindberg's version of the central limit theorem to a sequence always equal to $X$.

In order to do that, I need to show that Lindberg-Feller condition is satisfied, and, for that, I need $X$'s variance.

Is there an easier way to do this? (without using CLT) Can anyone give me a hint on how to calculate that variance?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: One does not assume that $X$, $Y$ and $(X+Y)/\sqrt2$ are i.i.d., only that $X$ and $Y$ are.

Comment: We solved this problem in probability class. I don't really recall the exact solution now, but I'm sure you can somehow show that the variance has to be finite. Try doing so by contradiction

Comment: @Did you are right, it's X,Y i.i.d. and X have the same distribution as $(X+Y)/\sqrt(2)$. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @mm-aops X's variance has to be 1, but i could not show it yet. However, i managed to proove that Lindberg-Feller condition is satisfied if X has finite variance.

Comment: you don't really need to check Lindeberg-Feller if X has finite variance, cause then it's obvious X has to have mean zero so it's just a simple case of the standard CLT for iid variables (you just take a subsequence $\frac{S_{2^n}}{2^{n/2}}$ where S_n is a sum of iid variables with distribution X. on one hand it has to converge to a normal distribution, on the other by your assumption it's distribution is always the same as X's. you can have any variance you want, just finite one. sorry, I don't remember how I proved it last time, if I have time I'll give it a try in the evening

Comment: @mm-aops i managed to do it yesterday, thanks for helping! I'll write the answer later today and upload it here.

Comment: @mm-aops Is it feasible to use $\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}$ to go through the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mm-aops mentioned, you don't need to use Lindeberg-Feller to do this.

The tricky part to prove $\mathbb E(X^2) < \infty$. The best I can think of is to follow the path in exercise 3.4.3 of [Probability: Theory and Examples](http://www.ime.usp.br/~manuelg/arquivos/Probability%3a%20Theory%20and%20Examples%20-%20Durrett.pdf), which says:

> 3.4.3. Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be i.i.d. and let $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. Assume that $S_n / \sqrt{n}$ converges to a limit in distribution and conclude that $\mathbb E X_i^2 < \infty$.

I believe that instead of requiring $S_n/\sqrt{n}$ to converge in probability, it is enough to require a subsequence $S_{n(k)} /\sqrt{n(k)}$ to converge in probability. Thus it can be applied to this question. For details, please check the sketch of proof in the book.

The rest is easy.

Since $X \sim (X+Y)/\sqrt{2}$, we have $\mathbb E(X) =  \sqrt{2}\mathbb E(X) $. Therefore $\mathbb E(X) = 0$.

Now assume $\mathbb E(X^2) < \infty$. Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with distribution $X$. Let $S_n = \sum_{m=1}^n X_m$. By Central Limit Theorem, we have
$$
\frac {S_{2^b}} {\sqrt{2^b}} \to \chi
$$
in probability when $b \to \infty$ through positive integers, where $\chi$ is the standard normal distribution. It follows from assumption that ${S_{2^b}} / {\sqrt{2^b}}$ actually has distribution $X$. Therefore $X$ must be standard normal.

Comment: Is it feasible to use $\frac{S_{2n}}{\sqrt{2n}}$ to go through the proof?